# npm lzf module installation failure

Tags: node.js, npm, lzf

I was trying to get the lzf module for my project, then an error occurred during the installation. Just as other people would have done I googled about the question, but couldn't find the right solution for my situation.

```
lzf@0.3.0 install /home/grewvr/node_modules/lzf
node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-    gyp/lib/configure.js:354:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/grewvr/node_modules/lzf
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN moskit@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "lzf"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! lzf@0.3.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lzf@0.3.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the lzf package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs lzf
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls lzf
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/grewvr/npm-debug.log
```

Been trying to fix the problem for two days, please help me.

Comment: Based on the open pull requests https://github.com/Topface/node-lzf/pulls the package itself is badly broken and is no longer maintained.

Comment: @AndyRay Thanks, think I might have to use another compression.